# show two different values in the same column-SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need to create a report(SSRS) ,but I can't figure out how i can get one specific  value.
Please consider the following scenario: I Have a Hierarchy Country ->City->Person ,& i need to get the value of the wealth in one column for a specific person ,a specific city & a specific  country.
the wealth of a counry is not the SUM of the wealth of the persons living in the country .
My report should look like :

### USA :                20M$

```
   NY:                  3M$
```

---

```
      Person1:        0,1M$ 
      Person2:        0,2M$

  Boston:             2M$

      Person 3:       0,5M$
```

................
My query is :

```
;WITH wealth_TEMP AS
(
    SELECT
        fo.wealthId,
        SUM(fo.wealth) AS wealth
        FROM
    (
        SELECT
            wealthId,
            CASE
                WHEN (Some Criteria)
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END AS wealth
        FROM wealthTable f
    ) fo
    GROUP BY wealthId
),
Hierarchy AS
(
    SELECT 
        B.CityId AS CityId,
        B.CountryName AS CountryName
    FROM HierarchyTable AS B where
     b.CountryName IN (@Country)
),
Person_Table AS
(
    SELECT
        fsu.individualId,
        fsu.Cityid,
        fo.welth
    FROM Individual_Table FSU
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wealth_TEMP fo ON fo.wealthId = fsu.individualId
    WHERE bu.Cityname IN (@City)
)
Select ......................
```

Comment: What are the values in @Country and @City? Are you passing in a list? Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: you needn't get that values in the same column in your query. Just set City.Value for cell in the CityGroupRow, and Person.Value in the PersonGroupRow in your report

Comment: Hello Sean ,yes the city & country are parameters i passing to the query.

Comment: Hello xdd , in the report i have other KPI's that are not using the same hierarchy ,but i ll give it a try.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your dataset returns something like it:

```
Country CountryWealth State    StateWealth Person     PersonWealth  
USA     20M$          NY       3M$         Person 1    0,1M$
USA     20M$          NY       3M$         Person 2    0,2M$
USA     20M$          Boston   2M$         Person 3    0,5M$
```

1. Create a table with 5 columns and remove the header line
2. Insert tow new details line
3. In the **first** line and **first** column configure to the Country and Hide Duplicates to true
4. In the **first** line and **second** column configure to the CountryWealth and Hide Duplicates to true
5. In the **second** line and **second** column configure to the State and Hide Duplicates to true
6. In the **second** line and **third** column configure to the StateWealth and Hide Duplicates to true
7. In the **third** line and **third** to the end configure the others values

Order the table to Country, State, person
May, you need to add more columns and merge to get your desired lyout

Comment: Thank you Mauricio , I'll try it.